# Express.js multer don't see text fields only file

Tags: ajax, express, reactjs, multer

When i use AJAX request to send multipart/form-data form to server containing picture and 3 text fields, multer process only image, but no text-fields. How to extract text fields from there?
`FormData constructor`

```
  handleSubmit = () => {
    let formData = new FormData(this.refs.productSubmit);
    this.props.submitProduct(formData);
  }
```

`Form`

```
<form action="javascript:void(0);" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} ref="productSubmit">
  <label> Название </label>
  <input className={'form-control'} type="text" name="name" />
  <label> Цена </label>
  <input className={'form-control'} type="text" name="price" />
  <label> Описание </label>
  <input className={'form-control'} type="text" name="description" />
  <label> Изображение </label>
  <input className={'form-control'} type="file" name="picture" style={{height: '100%'}}/>
  <hr/>
  <button className={'btn btn-warning btn-lg'} bsSize={'small'} type="submit"> Добавить </button>
</form>
```

`Async action creator with AJAX call inside`

```
export function submitProduct(formData) {
  return function(dispatch) {
    return (
      $.ajax({
        url: '/addproduct',
        method: 'post',
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        data: formData,
        success: data => {
          //dispatch(addedProduct());
        },
        error: (xhr, status, err) => {
          console.error(this.props.url, status, err.toString());
        }
      })
    );
  };
}
```

`Server-side request processer`

```
  app.post('/addproduct', isLoggedIn, isAdmin, upload.single('image'), (req, res) => {
    console.log(req);
    console.log(req.body);
    console.log(req.file);
});
```

But req.body is undefined. File is accessable. Fields ARE present in payload request, i can see them with firefox devtools.How to get thoose text fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Express 4.0 you need to manually add the [`body-parser`](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser) middleware, otherwise forms don't get parsed and `req.body` will be undefined.

In your main file, you should do something like this:

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

// ...

module.exports = app;
```